# Crash on calling addpersistentstorewithtype

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, crash, core-data-migration

I'm creating a `NSPersistentStore` with the code below, but it crashes with an error posted farther below.

```
- (NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *)persistentStoreCoordinator {

if (persistentStoreCoordinator != nil) {
    return persistentStoreCoordinator;
}

// Check if we need to copy initial database store
NSString *storePath = [[self applicationDocumentsDirectory]
                       stringByAppendingPathComponent: PersistentStoreFilename];
//[self checkPersistentStore:storePath];
NSURL *storeUrl = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:storePath];
// Enable automatic lightweight migration
NSDictionary *options = @{
                          NSMigratePersistentStoresAutomaticallyOption : @YES,
                          NSInferMappingModelAutomaticallyOption : @YES
                          };
NSError *error = nil;
NSDictionary *fileAttributes = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:NSFileProtectionComplete forKey:NSFileProtectionKey];
NSLog(@"fileAttributes ---- %@",fileAttributes);
NSLog(@"before file attributes - storePath ---- %@",storePath);
[[NSFileManager defaultManager] setAttributes:fileAttributes ofItemAtPath:storePath error:&error];

persistentStoreCoordinator = [[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator alloc]
                              initWithManagedObjectModel:[self managedObjectModel]];

NSLog(@"1.persistentStoreCoordinator ---- %@",persistentStoreCoordinator);
NSLog(@"2.applicationDocumentsDirectory ---- %@",[self applicationDocumentsDirectory]);
NSLog(@"3.PersistentStoreFilename ---- %@",PersistentStoreFilename);
NSLog(@"4.storePath ---- %@",storePath);
NSLog(@"4.storeUrl ---- %@",storeUrl);

NSLog(@"5)persistentStoreCoordinator ---- Error loading core data database");

if(![persistentStoreCoordinator addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType
                                             configuration:nil URL:storeUrl options:options error:&error]) {
    /*Error for store creation should be handled in here*/

    // REA - removing current store and replacing with one from bundle
    //        NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    //        [fileManager removeItemAtPath:storePath error:nil];
    //        [self checkPersistentStore:storePath];
    NSLog(@"First attempt addPersistentStoreWithType error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
    if(![persistentStoreCoordinator addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType
                                                 configuration:nil URL:storeUrl options:options error:&error]) {
        // Even the bundle version isn't loading - something really bad happened and we can't run
        NSLog(@"Second attempt addPersistentStoreWithType error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        NSLog(@"6)persistentStoreCoordinator ---- Error loading core data database");
        abort();
    }
}

return persistentStoreCoordinator;
}
```

It causes a crash and below are the `nslog` from the device.

> before file attributes - storePath ---- /var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/AA4EF2AA-1E72-4BC9-A939-732A1BB65E71/Documents/iPhoneCoreData.sqlite
>
> 1.persistentStoreCoordinator ----
>
> 2.applicationDocumentsDirectory ---- /var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/AA4EF2AA-1E72-4BC9-A939-732A1BB65E71/Documents
>
> 3.PersistentStoreFilename ---- iPhoneCoreData.sqlite
>
> 4.storePath ---- /var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/AA4EF2AA-1E72-4BC9-A939-732A1BB65E71/Documents/iPhoneCoreData.sqlite
>
> 4.storeUrl ---- file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/AA4EF2AA-1E72-4BC9-A939-732A1BB65E71/Documents/iPhoneCoreData.sqlite

Crash Logs:

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGKILL)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:  EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY
Termination Reason: Namespace SPRINGBOARD, Code 0x8badf00d
Termination Description: SPRINGBOARD, scene-create watchdog transgression: com.united.UnitedAgentMobileApp exhausted real (wall clock) time allowance of 19.27 seconds |  | ProcessVisibility: Foreground | ProcessState: Running | WatchdogEvent: scene-create | WatchdogVisibility: Foreground | WatchdogCPUStatistics: ( | "Elapsed total CPU time (seconds): 21.220 (user 21.220, system 0.000), 53% CPU", | "Elapsed application CPU time (seconds): 19.319, 48% CPU" | )
Triggered by Thread:  0

Back Trace:

Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: SQLQueue 0x117dc0080 for UnitediPhoneCoreData.sqlite
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libcompression.dylib            0x00000001841865d8 zlibDecodeBufferSafe + 40
1   libcompression.dylib            0x000000018418747c zlib_decode_stream_process + 288
2   libcompression.dylib            0x000000018418747c zlib_decode_stream_process + 288
3   CoreData                        0x000000018530d92c -[NSSQLiteConnection _decompressedModelWithData:] + 188
4   CoreData                        0x000000018530dc5c -[NSSQLiteConnection fetchCachedModel] + 552
5   CoreData                        0x00000001852e18b0 __34-[NSSQLCore cachedModelWithError:]_block_invoke + 112
6   CoreData                        0x00000001852301d4 -[NSSQLStoreRequestContext executeRequestUsingConnection:] + 248
7   CoreData                        0x00000001852b2118 __52-[NSSQLDefaultConnectionManager handleStoreRequest:]_block_invoke + 84
8   libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018239aa14 _dispatch_client_callout + 16
9   libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001823a3618 _dispatch_queue_barrier_sync_invoke_and_complete + 56
10  CoreData                        0x00000001852b2014 -[NSSQLDefaultConnectionManager handleStoreRequest:] + 256
11  CoreData                        0x00000001853a2524 -[NSSQLCoreDispatchManager routeStoreRequest:] + 264
12  CoreData                        0x00000001852e3fdc -[NSSQLCore dispatchRequest:withRetries:] + 236
13  CoreData                        0x00000001852e1738 -[NSSQLCore cachedModelWithError:] + 112
14  CoreData                        0x00000001852e297c +[NSSQLCore cachedModelForPersistentStoreWithURL:options:error:] + 688
15  CoreData                        0x00000001853363ac -[NSStoreMigrationPolicy sourceModelForStoreAtURL:metadata:error:] + 1256
16  CoreData                        0x00000001853379c8 -[NSStoreMigrationPolicy+ 1653192 (InternalMethods) _gatherDataAndPerformMigration:] + 772
17  CoreData                        0x00000001852bba34 __91-[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator addPersistentStoreWithType:configuration:URL:options:error:]_block_invoke + 2896
18  CoreData                        0x00000001852c956c gutsOfBlockToNSPersistentStoreCoordinatorPerform + 212
19  libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018239aa14 _dispatch_client_callout + 16
20  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001823a3618 _dispatch_queue_barrier_sync_invoke_and_complete + 56
21  CoreData                        0x00000001852b7944 _perform + 200
22  CoreData                        0x00000001851adfa4 -[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator addPersistentStoreWithType:configuration:URL:options:error:] + 384

Comment: You didn't copy/paste the error given in console.

Comment: I didn't receive any logs for the "NSLog(@"First attempt addPersistentStoreWithType error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
"

Comment: You got a crash but no message in console?

Comment: It is only crashing for a few particular devices.

Comment: @Larme - added back trace from the phone logs.

Answer (score 0):

So we followed the circuit breaker pattern and followed the below blog post to address the issue.

https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/core-data-from-scratch-migrations--cms-21844